# How to implement pdf.js library on cordova/phonegap 2.7.0?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

pdf.js library works perfect on the desktop browsers but when implemented on PhoneGap project,  the viewer interface of pdf.js library loads but the PDF files to be read fails to load. Can anyone help me with support for solving the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try mpdf.com I used it in my Cordova project. It's a server side php script. Works great.